# "In order to help serve you better..."

Tags: infinitives, transitivity

This sentence is from a Japanese book for English language learners. It's a transcript of a public announcement recording. I was asked whether the sentence is correct.

I am not a native speaker and to me, it sounds like something is missing. I would most likely say: "In order to help us serve you better..." or even "In order to help us to serve you better..."

Is the sentence correct and is it a common way to use it during a public announcement?

Answer (score 1):

> In order to help serve you better...

Is correct and understandable, additional ways to express this are:

> To help serve you better...
>   [Help us serve you better...](https://www.atriummedcenter.org/Patient-and-Visitor-Information/Quality/Help-Us-Serve-You-Better/)
>   [Please help us serve you better...](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/VC62HGK)

Phrases like these are commonly used in American English when asking for customer feedback.